# Unable to build GoogleApiClient

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

This is my code for building a googleApiClient:

```
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
```

However the second 'this' is underlined, as it it looking for a "connectionCallback" rather than an activity.

I tried to implement these when starting the class:

```
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

However, I get this error:

```
Class MapsActivity must be either declared abstract or implement abstract method 'OnConnectionSuspended(int)' in 'ConnectionCallbacks'
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Edit: This is not a duplicate for another question as it is a different scenario and the answer does not seem to apply to this situation. Even so, i unable to solve this.

Comment: You need to override all methods of ConnectionCallbacks.

Comment: It perfectly applies.  Did you not even google what that error means?

Comment: @Drv solved it. Case closed.

Comment: @J.Tey can you post your solution, I am having the same situation here.

Comment: You need to override all methods of ConnectionCallbacks. Click on the red light bulb and click the first option.